# PHP $_POST array is empty for no apparent reason (XAMPP?)

Tags: php, arrays, post, xampp

I have a problem, my form opens another PHP script with post method, but it doesn't pass on any values. I tried fixes such as setting in php.ini:

```
post_max_size = 8M
variables_order = "EGPCS"
```

and

Didn't work. Here's the form code:

```
<form enctype="text/plain" action="zalogujCheck.php" name="com-login" method="post" id="com-form-login">
                <label for="username">Nazwa użytkownika</label>
                <input name="username" id="username" type="text" class="inputbox input-long" alt="username" />
                <label for="passwd">Hasło</label>
                <input type="password" name="passwd" id="passwd" type="text" class="inputbox input-long" alt="password" />
            <input type="submit" value="Zatwierdź" name="submit">
        </form>
```

Here's the PHP for this form:

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' )
  {
     echo "otwarte postem";
 print_r($_POST);
  }
echo "początek2";
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
    $USER=$_POST["username"];
    echo "ustawiłem username";
}
if(isset($_POST["passwd"])){
    $PASS=$_POST["passwd"];
    echo "ustawiłem passwd";
}
?>
```

Result is:

```
otwarte postemArray ( ) początek2
```

I am using XAMPP, don't know how much of an impact my choice has. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As a general troubleshooting rule, you should first use a browser addon like Firebug or Chrome's inbuilt dev features to see if you're actually sending POST variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `enctype="text/plain"` from the `<form>` element.

The default is `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, which is fine (so you don't need to specify it explicitly). Only if you have an `<input type="file">` in your form, you should specify `enctype="multipart/form-data"` explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's a copy-paste slap stick for me :). Don't know form too well yet.